# Why is the min-width applied to body tag not being respected by fixed div?

Tags: html, css, position, width, fixed

Layout: I have a div that is fixed on the top right and that has a width of 100% and a height of 50px. (This is my fixed header) Inside of the fixed div I have another div that has a position: relative. (That div with a position: relative is used for centering purposes). Inside of the div with position: relative, I have a few icons.

I have given my body tag a min-width of 400px. When the viewport gets smaller than 400px, the min-width: 400px triggers and works as intended on everything on the page except the fixed div.

The icons in the fixed div start to push against each other and look very messy. The min-width 400px doesnt work in this case, but why?

This fixed div is inside of my body tag, so why would the min-width 400px applied to my body tag not work on this fixed header, while it's working everywhere else?

Please, just explain me what is the reason it doesn't behave as it should?

Comment: your fixed div only sees the window's size since it is not part of the flow anymore, this is the normal behavior.. look at position:sticky or absolute if you want a parent to be the reference.  see https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/position

Comment: So I have to give that fixed div a min width of 440px also? So  both the body and that fixed width need to have a min-width of 440px? So any element that is fixed on my page needs to have a min-width of 400px? ...

Comment: Applying width or min-width to the body is not good practice. Use a container instead.